# Controller parameters via URL or POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel to deliver a search page with the following routes:

```
Route::get('/search', 'PagesController@search');
Route::get('/search/{q}', 'PagesController@search');
Route::post('/search', 'PagesController@search');
```

The first route handles a visit to the search page which should display a search form.
The second route expects a parameter on the URL that allows for bookmarking of searches.
The third route receives the form from the first page as a POST and handles the search.

Each of three routes tries to use a single function within the PagesController.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('q')) {
        $q = $request->input('q');
    }

    if ($q) {
        $models = Model::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%") 
                ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                ->take(10)
                ->get();

        return view('pages.search', [ 'models' => $models, 'query' => $q ]);
    }

    return view ('home')->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');       
}
```

My question is how do I get the single Controller function to handle the three routes? To pass in the {q} from the URL I think I need to add another parameter to the search function, but this then fails on the two routes that do not have the {q}.

In this situation is it a case of a separate function for each kind of response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the code clean, I would suggest making separate functions.  One for showing the form, one for the POST, and one for the bookmark.  It is a little easier to maintain than the if-branches and a little easier to read.

However, to directly answer your question, you can keep it all in one if you prefer.  Just add an optional parameter to the method like so:

```
public function search(Request $request, $q = false){}
```

By giving `$q` a default of false, the incoming routes without the variable will not fail.  It also allows for a simple if-check (`if($q)...`).

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the answer, explaining both options. Really kicking myself now

Comment: Nah - easy thing to overlook.  Glad it helped!

Comment: Or, `if($request->has('foo') && ($foo = $request->input('foo'))` - assign it in the expression, whilst checking. Then you can use it as `$foo` - in this example.